# Error bound for Gaussian Quadrature

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, numerical-calculus

Suppose that x$_1$ , x$_2$ , ... x$_N$, are the roots of a polynomial ortoghonal to the measure w(x) in the interval [a,b] $\subset \mathbf{R} $. We know then that gaussian quadrature formula is exact for all polynomials of degree less than 2N.

In order to evaluate the integral of f(x) in the interval [a,b] we use this theorem: $$ f(x) - P_n(x) = \frac{f^{(n)}(\xi(x))}{(n)!} \Pi_{i=1}^{N} (x-x_i)$$ = R_n(x)

where $P_n(x)$ is such that $P_n(x_i) = f(x_i)$ and $\xi(x) \in$ [a,b]

Using gaussian quadrature the error we make is $$ E_n[f] = \int_{a}^b R_n(x) dx $$

How can we show that the error is in reality this quantity: $$ \frac{f^{(2n)}(\xi)}{(2n)!} \int_{a}^b \left( \Pi_{i=1}^N (x-x_i) \right)^2 dx$$

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Gauss integration uses a Hermite interpolation polynomial, and chooses the node points such that the coefficients of the derivative have value zero. Thus the squares in the error term for the duplicated node points, and the correspondingly higher order of the derivative.

Comment: I think I do not have a key step. My teacher (I'm a physicist) never spoke about Hermite interpolation polynomial and he just told us, without proof, that it's possible to derive that formula for the error using a generic integration measure w(x). Do you know where I can study what you are referring to?

Answer (score 2):

As you want order $2n$, you need at least $2n$ points if the integration formula were based on Lagrange interpolation. These points can be freely chosen. So select them so that for each point $x_k$ you take two points $x_k\pm\epsilon$.
This $\epsilon$ only serves to go from the Lagrange interpolation to Hermite interpolation, it can be arbitrarily small independent of the configuration of the $x_k$.

Denote the usual Lagrange kernels for $x_1,...,x_n$ as
$$
L_k(x)=\prod_{j=1,\,j\ne k}^n\frac{x-x_j}{x_k-x_j}
$$
Then the interpolation for the set of $2n$ points is
\begin{align}
f(x)&=\sum_{k=1}^nf(x_k+ϵ)\frac{x-(x_k-ϵ)}{(x_k+ϵ)-(x_k-ϵ)}(L_k(x)^2+O(ϵ))
\\&~~~~~+f(x_k-ϵ)\frac{x-(x_k+ϵ)}{(x_k-ϵ)-(x_k+ϵ)}(L_k(x)^2+O(ϵ))+E_ϵ(x)
\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^nf(x_k)L_k(x)^2+\sum_{k=1}^nf'(x_k)(x-x_k)L_k(x)^2+E(x)+O(ϵ)
\end{align}
where likewise
$$
E_ϵ(x)=E(x)+O(ϵ), ~~~ E(x)=R(x)\prod_{k=1}^n(x-x_k)^2,
$$
and $R(x)=f[x,x_1,x_1,x_2,x_2,...,x_n,x_n]$ is a generalized divided difference from the Newton interpolation formula. It is a continuous function in $x$ and can be represented as
$$
R(x)=\frac{f^{(2n)}(\xi_x)}{(2n)!}
$$

---

The aim of the Gauss integration rule is to not have the derivatives of $f$ in the formula. Thus the integral over these terms has to be zero
$$
0=\int_a^b (x-x_k)L_k(x)^2\,dx
$$
This gives a system of $n$ polynomial equations for the $n$ numbers $x_1,...,x_n$. With some clever transformations one can describe the polynomial $P(x)=\prod_{j=1}^n(x-x_j)\sim (x-x_k)L_k(x)$ that has these numbers as roots. The above equation can be interpreted as that this polynomial is orthogonal to all $L_k$ in the standard $L^2$ scalar product. Thus it is orthogonal to all polynomials of degree less than $n$, which after a little consideration of the formula of partial integration gives
$$P(x)=\frac{n!}{(2n)!}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}[((x-b)(x-a))^n].$$

---

Once this is solved, the quadrature rule now reads
$$
\int_a^bf(x)\,dx=\sum_{k=1}^n w_kf(x_k)+\int_a^b R(x)P_n(x)^2\,dx
=...+\frac{f^{(2n)}(\xi_c)}{(2n)!}\int_a^b P_n(x)^2\,dx
\\~\\
w_k=\int_a^b L_k(x)^2\,dx
$$
where $c$ is the midpoint from the mean value theorem for integrals and $\xi_c$ the midpoint from converting the divided difference into a derivative.